# CSS3 link style not being picked up consistently

Tags: html, css

My code was all working correctly until I did a CSS3 validation which told me I needed to move the @import font code line to the first line in the css style file. When, I did that of course I realized the web fonts I had chosen had not been displaying, so I fixed all the sizes, etc. to best display the pages with the chosen fonts.

I can't seem to figure out this last quirk, though. The p a:link, a:visited color blue is not being picked up in the p tags, except for one place in the footnote area (footnote #6)! The other a links within p tags are picking the white color up from the insert-container p a styles. I understand that the last style overrides previous ones, but the selectors are different, so I'm not understanding why this is happening.

I've cleared the cache, tried different browsers, tried changing the colors on each of the a link styles, but if I change it to fix the paragraph text, then it ends up also changing the insert-container link styles.

You can see the issue on my CodePen at https://codepen.io/Ovimel/pen/XQjgeg and the CSS is shown below. Thanks!

**CSS3**

```
/*styling for paragraph text links */
p a {
  font-weight: 900;
}

p a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #194a76;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #194a76;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* styling for colored page inserts from xopixel dot com */
#fullwidth-insert {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: #7d654b;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Carme", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.insert-container {
  max-width: 85%;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.insert-heading {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.08rem;
}

/* styling for full-width insert heading links */
.insert-heading a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Days One", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.insert-heading a:hover,
a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #194a76;
}

/* styling for full-width insert paragraph links */
.insert-container p a:link,
a:visited {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.insert-container p a:hover,
a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #194a76;
}

/*styling for footnotes*/
p.footnote {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  /*10 pt 13px */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Higher specificity will beat out order in the stylesheet. This selector:

```
.insert-container p a:link
```

has higher specificity than this one:

```
p a:link
```

You can see the selector is more specific as it targets links inside a `p` inside the `.insert-container` div. For more on the how it is calculated by the browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Thank you @Simran. I read through the info you linked to, understand the specificity, and tried some of the suggestions (!important;), but as a novice coder, I can't seem to create a workaround. At some point everything changes together, except of course for footnote #6 which does what it is supposed to do! Crazy.

Comment: Best suggestion is to make the base style by creating a very low specificity rule, then it is easy to override with more specific selectors. You should not need `!important`. Try making the basic link style with simple selector, something like `a { color: blue }`, then override with more complex selectors like `.insert-container a { color: white }`. Dont give up!

Comment: So are you saying to take out the p tag from the style code p a {color: blue}? I tried that on the areas not conforming, but it didn't make a difference. Maybe I have to do that all the way down the p a style codes? And, if I do, how will that effect other a links in code such as in the nav bar and flexbox cards I have? I'll play with it! @simran